# Azure blob storage : check blob mime type when upload from the browser

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Azure web storage allows to upload blobs directly from the browser using shared access signatures (SAS).

Examples:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2018/10/25/azure-storage-blob-upload-from-browser/
- https://medium.com/@stuarttottle/upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-angular-7977e979496a

It works fine but I am wondering about security.

There is not in that case any server to check the mime type of the updloaded file.

I check the mime type of the file in the browser before uploading it but I want to check it also on "the server".

As there is no server, I tried to use an Azure Logic app who triggers when a new blob is added.

But this is not the solution:

- The check is only based on the file extension,
- The check cannot be triggered as soon as the blob is uploaded and cannot send any response to the client.

Do you have any idea to check the mime type of a blob uploaded to Azure directly from the browser?

Comment: `It works fine but I am wondering about security` - Can you elaborate more on why you're concerned about security?

Comment: Because uploaded files as for all other user inputs cannot be trusted and must be checked server side.

Comment: Good question, the same issue.